# Como retornar texto Json do BD para ArrayList no Java

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, json, arraylist

Estou tendo problemas ao converter um conjunto de textos no formato Json do banco de dados para um conjunto de textos em ArrayList no Java. Segue o código abaixo:

Model.java

```
public class Sala {
     private String professor;
     private ArrayList<Aluno> alunos;

     //gets e sets...
}

public class Aluno {
      private String nome;
      private String matricula;

      //gets e sets...
}
```

DAO.java

```
public ArrayList<Sala> obterInformacoesSala(){
     ...
     try{
        while(rs.next()){
            Sala s = new Sala();
            s.setProfessor(rs.getString("professor"));
            s.setAlunos(???); //tipo Json no BD
        }
     } catch { ... }
}
```

Comment: Não estou conseguindo retornar os dados de dentro do json em forma de arraylist

Comment: Por exemplo, dentro de alunos tem 'nome' e 'matricula'. E eu preciso pegar esses dados, que compõem um objeto json e preencher um arraylist do tipo Aluno, que faz parte da Sala

Comment: Bom dia, Se entendi bem sua dúvida acredito que isso possa te ajudar: Seu problema é o parse entre objetos java e json né, existe algumas bibliotecas que vão te ajudar umas dela é o Jackson e outra o Gson, segue alguns exemplos de uso: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-jsonparser.html
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-jsonparser.html http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson-jsonparser.html
http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/